# How to implement a responsive Pinterest-style layout with Zurb Foundation and SASS mixins?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation with SASS and Compass.  I need to implement a  [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) style column layout , where each "panel/pin" can have a different  height but all panels/pins have the same width. The challenge is to lay them without vertical gaps; using 'css float' leaves vetical gaps.  I have been experimenting with various grid options in Zurb Foundation with little sucess.  Is there a mixin to achieve  Pinterest style layout?

Comment: Is there a question here?  Unless you have some idea of what the desired CSS should be, Sass can't help you.

Comment: They seem to be using position:absolute on Pinterest, and then javascript to calculate positioning on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need more tools than just foundation. I suggest you try adding this to your project http://masonry.desandro.com/

Or

More robust, but not free for commercial use.
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/